# Apache FOP Issue

Tags: xslt, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an application that uses Apache FOP to produce a PDF from some data object. This data object is a collection of String attributes of which some may contain non breaking space escape sequences. These escape sequences are coded as `"&#160;"`.

The problem I am facing is that the PDF shows `&#160;` instead of a space!

I need to show several spaces in my PDF. Putting several space characters in my data instead of several `"&#160;"` escape sequences results in a single space being rendered which is too small.

I am not familiar with XSLT as another team member has produced the stylesheet so my understanding is as below.

Here is a section from my XSLT template..

```
<fo:block
  font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold"
  linefeed-treatment="preserve" margin-left="5pt">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="drawee" />
</fo:block>
```

I understant that the above will send to the output PDF whatever is in the input under the name "drawee". Sometimes, the input data reffered to as "drawee" needs to contain non breaking spaces and specifying those as `&#160;` does not produce the right result in the PDF.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: "Coded as" means they are literally inserted as such? Seems like you are counting on FOP to translate this XML/HTML notation. Does this work for other similar entries? Does it work correctly when you insert this character as UTF-8?

Comment: [This might help...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013570/how-to-add-newline-after-an-xml-node-so-that-fop-will-recognize-whitespace/)

Comment: As I understand it, &#160; is what should be entered in an XML file for a non breaking space. I assumed that FOP would also treat this as a non breaking space

Comment: `&#160;` in XSL-FO code is rendered correctly by Apache FOP. Even if you were not the one who wrote the XSLT code, we need to see XML input (especially the part with an element named `drawee`).

Comment: There are no "data objects" really in FO or XSLT - please use a correct term to describe this. Do you perhaps mean "input XML" or "stylesheet parameter"?

Comment: Looking at the code, a "data object" is used to create a SAXSource object which is then transformed into a SAXResult object. There is no XML that I can see. All I know is that the "data object" has a method called getDrawee() and that the string returned by this method appears in the output PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps several non-breaking spaces are collapsed during the transformation. Try:

You'll find the relevant part of the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space-collapse).

```
<fo:block
  font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold"
  linefeed-treatment="preserve" whitespace-collapse="false" margin-left="5pt">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="drawee" />
</fo:block>
```

If that does not help, it might be interesting to try and hard-code the breaks instead of retrieving it from an element.

```
<fo:block
  font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold"
  linefeed-treatment="preserve" whitespace-collapse="false" margin-left="5pt">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="start&#160;&#160;&#160;end" />
</fo:block>
```

Side note: If you'd like to insert whitespace between other text content, `fo:inline` might be better suited because `fo:block` are treated as separate paragraphs.

Comment: @PatrickLucas You're welcome. Please consider accepting this question (mark the tick on the left) if it solved your problem.